# What technique to use to inject a DLL?

Tags: c++, dll-injection

I am trying to inject a DLL into another process with not much success. While doing my research I found out that there is more then one way to do this. The question is : What is the optimal way or When should I use let's say CreateRemoteThread() instead of LoadLibrary()?

Comment: `CreateRemoteThread` with an address of `LoadLibrary` (after allocating memory in there to hold my DLL path) did the trick for me in XP, but not on 7 for whatever reason. I didn't pursue it much further, as I was just playing around anyway.

Comment: Actually, I'm really only looking to understand windows api. I'm a total noob in c++ but I enjoy the security aspect of computers. I'm studying in software engineer and I'm looking forward to work in the security industry. (Sorry my english is not perfect :D, but you get the point!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)?

Also this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. It looks very interresting I'Ll take a look at it.